# Using .pdf in Kile: cannot determine size of graphics

Tags: graphics, pdftex, kile

I am using Kile on a Red Hat/Gnome desktop at my university. My figures are made in R on a Windows machine. When I try to add figures to my `report` class LaTeX document, using the following code:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
 \includegraphics[width = 0.9\textwidth]{path/biomass_dried_glm.pdf}
\end{figure}
```

I get the error message: `Cannot determine size of graphic in path/blah` (it doesn't say anything about bounding box anymore).

I have looked around, and understand that it has something to do with the dvpdf or something, but if anyone could help me change the settings in Kile or tell me what to do in Kile I would be very happy.

Comment: You are trying to use a PDF with `latex` in DVI mode. Simply use `pdflatex` instead and you should be fine.

Comment: I need it in with a teaspoon - how exactly can I do that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Oh, yes, it works when compiling :) - but is there no way to make it work for the QuickBuild option?

Comment: @Anna: could you check the current configuration for QuickBuild? It might be easier for us to find out what's happening. `:)`

Comment: Go to `Settings -> Configure Kile -> Tools-Build`. Select `QuickBuild` from the list on the left. From the dropdown menu under the heading `Choose a configuration...`, select `PdfLatex+ViewPdf`. Save this configuration. Invoking QuickBuild from the main program interface should now trigger PdfLatex.

Comment: @MichaelPalmer Please turn your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Go to `Settings -> Configure Kile -> Tools -> Build`. Select `QuickBuild` from the list on the left. From the dropdown menu under the heading `Choose a configuration...`, select `PdfLatex + ViewPdf`. Save this configuration. Invoking QuickBuild from the main program interface should now trigger PdfLatex.